# Why doesn't predict_prob work in my model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My classification model prints out the accuracy when I use scikit-learn's *predict* function. However, when I try to use *predict_proba*, I receive an error.

```
model1 = LogisticRegression()
model1 = model1.fit(matrix_tmp, label_tmp)
y_train_pred = model1.predict_proba(matrix_tmp_test)
print(metrics.accuracy_score(label_tmp_test, y_train_pred))
```

The error I receive is:

```
ValueError: Can't handle mix of binary and continuous-multioutput
```

I am not sure why this error crops up when scikit-learn documentation says that both versions of predict except X (an array like matrix)

Comment: What shape and dtype has `label_tmp`

Comment: @MaxNoe label_tmp is a numpy array of dtype=np.int64. Shape is (7,)

Comment: Can you please show label_tmp_test and y_train_pred that you get.

Comment: @Farseer  label_tmp_test= ['20011' '20048' '20011' '20048'] 
It is a set of topics.
And y_train_pred= [[ 0.43269643  0.56730357]
 [ 0.43269643  0.56730357]
 [ 0.29652243  0.70347757]
 [ 0.43269643  0.56730357]]

Comment: There is your problem. label_tmp_test is array of strings, but y_train_pred is floats. Also, because dimensionality of y_train_pred is (x,2) i assume label_tmp include only two classes?

Comment: @Farseer Yes, label_tmp has only 2 classes because I am testing how does the classification work internally. How can I get them to be of compatible data types?

Comment: What predict_proba returns is probability for each label. Look at this probability and decide what label to give to test_example, for example use argmax(highest probability label).